# How to use AppleScript to position a window

Tags: ios, macos, applescript

How do I from console, position the window of an app using only its processID?

I have tried many variations of the following with no luck

```
tell application "System Events"
    set position of front window of process "32209" to {1, 1}
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
set pid to "32209"
tell application "System Events"
    set proc to item 1 of (processes whose unix id is pid)
    tell proc
        set position of front window to {1, 1}
    end tell
end tell
```

Be sure to use the correct process ID.

**Update (based on comment below)**

To move ALL windows belonging to the application, change

```
set position of front window to {1, 1}
```

to

```
set position of every window to {1, 1}
```

Comment: thats where i am stuck. This works, but when there are two instances of the same app on the screen, only one screen get moved and not the other. The items on the screen i am trying to arrange are 2 iOS simulators.

Comment: Gotcha. Your question did not mention multiple windows, but this is easy to address -- I have updated my answer above.